# Setter error using ChangeNotifierProxyProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am try pass string from `Model1` to `Model2` use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`, but it give error:

> No setter named ‘string’ in class ‘Model2’

**Model1**:

```
class Model1 extends ChangeNotifier {
...
final String string = 'hello';
}
```

**ChangeNotifierProxyProvider**:

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
      builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
        ..string = model1.string,
    ),
```

**Model2**:

```
class Model2 extends ChangeNotifier {

String _string;
String get string => _string;

}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You declared the property as read-only.

It cannot be `final`, and should instead have both a getter and a setter.

Either change it to:

```dart
String _string;
String get string => _string;
set string(String value) => _string = value;
```

or:

```dart
String string;
```

Comment: If I use `String string;` it throw error: `NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'string=' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: string="hello"`